# c# how to get mail name (uid) after send

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I want to read E-Mail Name.

example:"281a87c6-9d53-4122-99a1-87c2b4fb4259.eml"

how to get mail name (281a87c6-9d53-4122-99a1-87c2b4fb4259)

```
   smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
     smtp.PickupDirectoryLocation = @"C:\Temp";
     smtp.Send(message); 
...
```

Comment: Your question is far from being clear... what do you want to do here?

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: You should add what you want to achieve to your question, and maybe also an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read **all** of the email **file names** in the `C:\Temp` directory like so: -

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp");
foreach (FileInfo fInfo in dirInfo.GetFiles("*.eml*"))
{
     Console.WriteLine(fInfo.Name);
}
Console.Read();
```

You could potentially get the the newest created file in that directory which would give you the last email sent, though I'm not exactly sure what it is you're trying to achieve: -

```
var file = (from f in dirInfo.GetFiles("*.eml*")
             orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
             select f).First();
```

Which would return the newest email created (e.g. the one you just sent) in the `C:\Temp` dir.